# .net core equivalent for IHttpContext and HttpApplication

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have library using System.Web.HttpContext which I am migrating to .net core. Wondering what I should be using for IHttpContext and HttpApplication

Comment: Searching your question title in Google gives us as the first result this [Migrating HTTP handlers and modules to ASP.NET Core middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/http-modules). Maybe this can help

Comment: Yes I have seen this document, may be I was not clear. I couldn't find the properties that are on System.Web.HttpContext and HttpApplication(entirely removed in .net core?) in .net core. For example : HttpContext.Server HttpApplication.OnError event

Comment: With `ASP.NET Core`, we no longer have `System.Web.dll` or anything directly related to that. We instead have middleware, which is pluggable pieces that fit together cohesively. Pankaj addressed the `IHttpContextAccessor` portion correctly. And for the `HttpApplication` that no longer exists at all.

Comment: I want to collect the error occured lately on the server. I was using something like this in .net 4.5 : 
`var context = HttpContext.Current;
            var lastException = context.Server.GetLastError();`
How can I achieve this ?

Comment: @My3 You should change your question than to "How to I get the last error in ASP" and tag the question asp.net-core

Answer (score 0):

You can use IHttpContextAccessor to access context. To use IHttpContextAccessor use following steps.

1. Register dependency in ConfigureServices method of Startup.cs

   ```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
       services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
        //.....
   }
   ```

---

2. Inject IHttpContextAccessor wherever its required. e.g.

   ```
   public void MyController(IHttpContextAccessor context)
   {
      var user = context.HttpContext.User
   }
   ```